# PC does not post, random beep codes

Tags: boot, motherboard, desktop-computer

I have a basic PC that does not boot. The fans come on, the led light comes on, there is no signal on the monitor, no usb lights, a light comes on a PS/2 mouse.

I put a speaker on the motherboard to get a beep code and each time I turn the computer on I get a different code (AMI). 3 beeps, six beeps, 9 beeps and even 12 beeps. I'm confused why I get several different beep codes.

I've tried using a different PSU.

The PC would sometimes freeze or restart randomly.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that level of randomness, I would suspect it's the motherboard (mainboard) that's on it's way out or realistically dead already.

The only way to be 100% sure is either test all major components else where (cpu, ram, video card, hdd, PSU. OR replace the mainboard.

One thing to try first, is to reduce it to it's minimum. A cpu, some memory, and video card if required (and PSU), unplug everything else.

If it's still the same, you know it can only be one of those 4(5), and if I were betting, I would be putting my money on the mainboard. BUT it could be the CPU, more likely the mainboard.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it helps as it is a answer to why there are random beeps. I tested another PSU and the hard drive works in another PC. I have not tested the memory as I do not have any DDR3. I'll try a new motherboard!